# Raspberry Pi not visible on Windows Explorer

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, home-automation

I use a Raspberry Pi 3B+ for Home Assistant. It ran well for a few weeks, but suddenly it didn't work anymore. Now I can not even access the Raspberry Pi anymore through Windows Explorer. Does anybody have an idea why this happens?

The Raspberry has a fixed IP address, which is visible if I run, e.g. "advanced IP scanner". But as already mentioned, it does not work if I access it through Windows Explorer. Home Assistant does not work neither...

I am new, so I don't have much experience.

Comment: windows explorer is a file manager ... how were you accessing the RPi?

Answer (score 1):

> The raspberry has a fixed IP address...

If you ***have made*** a **DHCP Static Mapping** in your router/DHCP server that corresponds to the `static ip` setting you've made in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, please ignore the remainder of this answer.

If you ***haven't made*** a corresponding entry in your router/DHCP server, please direct your attention to the `static value` heading of `man dhcpcd.conf`, and note this statement from the author of `dhcpcd`:

> > For IPv4, you should use the inform ipaddress option instead of setting a static address.

And so, in spite of the many *ill-advised* suggestions to the contrary, you will be best-served by following the author's advice. It's not so much that the `static value` option is always the *wrong thing to do*, it's that many users see the `static value` option as being a complete configuration - it is not. The router/DHCP server is also involved in DHCP, and you ignore it at your peril and frustration. The `inform` option (or alternatively the `request` option) **may** provide you with the static IP address you think you need, while keeping the router/DHCP server ***"informed"***.

Even when using the `inform` option, you be cognizant of your router/DHCP server's configuration. For example, if you randomly choose an IP address, **and** that address is already assigned to another host, `inform` will fail silently (unless you monitor your logs).